# Release for book of interviews

Tags: self-publishing, legal, non-fiction, ebook

I would like to write an ebook in which I ask people to share their experiences in a specific topic.  Where can I find a good release for these people to sign?  Do I have to pay the interviewee?  Should there be verbiage regarding pay in the release?

Answer (score 2):

There are many sample release forms available. They are routinely used by bodies that are experienced in this matter, such as universities and the press. Here's a selection of forms for you to look over:

- [Association of American University Presses’ Sample Interview Release](https://www.dukeupress.edu/Assets/Downloads/DUP_SampleInterviewRelease.pdf)
- [Interview release form - Library of Congress](https://www.loc.gov/folklife/edresources/edcenter_files/samplereleaseforms.pdf)
- [University of Michigan Press - Interview Release Form](https://www.press.umich.edu/authors/Interview_Release_Form.pdf)
- [American Civil Liberties Union (ACLU) - Sample Consent and Release Forms](https://www.aclu.org/files/assets/3%205%20Interview%20Guide%20Sample%20Consent%20and%20Release%20Forms.pdf)

You will need to alter the above to suit your needs.

Here's a little advice from the Copyright and Fair Use section of the Stanford University Libraries website:

> ... a written interview release can be useful. It can help avoid
>   lawsuits for libel, invasion of privacy, or even copyright
>   infringement (since the speaker’s words may be copyrightable). It’s
>   wise to obtain a signed release if the interview is lengthy, will be
>   reprinted verbatim (for example, in a question and answer format), or
>   if the subject matter of the interview is controversial.

As for payment: no, don't offer it. As this website explains ([Myth: You Have To Pay The Other Person Money To Do An Interview With You](https://thejimedwardsmethod.com/myth-you-have-to-pay/)) there are other benefits for both parties aside from money, so find people to interview who can be persuaded of those benefits.

Good luck with your project.